# Error C1903 - unable to recover from previous errors when calling offsetof

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I have a weird error when I compile my project on MSVC.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 15 2017 and I compile in c++17 (MSVC version 15.6.85.37198)

The code compiles on Clang and G++ but it gives me an error on MSVC.

I managed to reduce the code causing the error to the following snippet :

```
#include <cstddef>

struct Point {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

template<class... Ps>
void doSomething() {
    offsetof(Point, x);
}

int main() {
    doSomething();
}
```

It gives me the following error :

```
main.cpp(10): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation [build\example.vcxproj]
```

I was a bit puzzled at first since it was the only error and it took me quite some time before I could identify that the problem came from offsetof.

The problem come from using the `offsetof` macro inside a templated function that takes a parameter pack in.

I do not think this code is doing anything illegal or is using undefined behavior. So, is the problem on my end or is it a bug in the compiler ?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you call `doSomething<>();` (note the `<>`)?

Comment: Yes, it loses its marbles pretty badly.  Very hard to provide a workaround when the code is so synthetic.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know.

Comment: @YSC I have the same error, with or without `<>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Point` is a [standard layout type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout), the use of `offsetof(Point, x)` is well-defined.

The fact that MSVC17 fails to compile your minimal example is surely a bug due to its incapability to support template parameter packs completely.

Comment: I sent an email to report the issue, hoping it will be fixed soon, in the meantime I'll be back to adding `sizeof` of my attributes